# Clean up of the "discussion-board" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I stumbled upon the [discussion-board](/questions/tagged/discussion-board) tag earlier, and I discovered...

- About 69 questions are tagged with it
- Only a handful of questions are adequately tagged, per the tag Wiki
- The lions' share of questions are either inadequately tagged or completely off-topic for the site.

I'm not saying that the tag needs to be burninated, but it definitely needs some help.

Anyone else interested?  I'll likely be starting with the improperly tagged questions first.

Comment: Look like one user put that tag on all of his android questions.

Comment: Seems like it.  Some of those are duplicates of each other, but a few of them *can* be salvaged.